# Prove that $f:\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)\to \mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ by $f(x)=xz$ is an isomorphism only if $z$ is divisible by $p$.

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Consider the Pr$\ddot{\text{u}}$fer $p$-group $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ (where $p$ is a prime number).   Define $f:\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)\to \mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ by $f(x)=xz$ for all $x\in \mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ and $z\in \mathbb{Z}$.  Then prove that $f$ is an isomorphism only if $z$ is not divisible by $p$.

Proof. For any $x\in \mathbb{Z}(p^\infty), x=a/p^n+\mathbb{Z}$ with $a/p^n\in \mathbb{Q}, a\in \mathbb{Z},n\in \mathbb{N}$.   If $z$ is divisible by $p$, then $f(x)=xz=x(tp)=(a/p^n+\mathbb{Z})tp=b/p^m+\mathbb{Z}$.  Hence for any $y=a/p^m+\mathbb{Z}\in \mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ there exists $x=a/p^n+\mathbb{Z}\in \mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ such that $f(x)=y$.  This gives $f$ surjective.

My problem is in

(1) proving injectivity of $f$

(2) How to prove that $f$ is not injective if $z$ is not divisible by $p$.

For (1):   $\ker(f)=\{a/p^n+\mathbb{Z}\in\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty): (a/p^n+\mathbb{Z})tp=\mathbb{Z}\}=\{a/p^m+\mathbb{Z} =\mathbb{Z} \}$. Which is possible if $a/p^m=0$.  This seems not to make sense for me.

Comment: It should be the opposite : $f$ is an isomorphism if and only if $z$ is *not* divisible by $p$

Comment: Yes, it was a typo! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the commutative diagram$\require{AMScd}$:
\begin{CD}
\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z@>\theta_n>>\Bbb Z(p^\infty)\\
@Vf_nVV@VVfV\\
\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z@>>\theta_n>\Bbb Z(p^\infty)
\end{CD}
where $\theta_n$ is the canonical homomorphism into the direct limit, which is injective.
If $f$ is injective, then each $f_n$ is injective as well, hence $p\nmid z$ (otherwise $p^{n-1}\in\ker f_n$).
Conversely, if $p\nmid z$, then each $f_n$ is injective, hence:
\begin{align}
\ker f
&=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\theta_n[\ker(f\circ\theta_n)]\\
&=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\theta_n[\ker(\theta_n\circ f_n)]\\
&=\{0\}
\end{align}