# Prove that the multiplication map $\mathbb{Z} ( p^\infty) \to \mathbb{Z} ( p^\infty)$ by $p^t$ is a surjective homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $ G=\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. Let $p$ be a prime integer and $\bar{<\frac{1}{p^n}>} $ is the subgroup generated by $\bar{\frac{1}{p^n}}$. Let $\mathbb{Z} ( p^\infty)= \bigcup_{p>0} \bar{<\frac{1}{p^n}>}$. Prove the following:
>
> The multiplication map $\mathbb{Z} ( p^\infty) \to \mathbb{Z} ( p^\infty)$ by $p^t$ is a surjective homomorphism. And find the kernel of this map.

My attempt:

Suppose that

$$f:\mathbb{Z} ( p^\infty) \to \mathbb{Z} ( p^\infty)$$

$$f(\overline {\frac {1}{p^n}})= \overline {\frac {p^t}{p^n}}$$

1. $f(\overline {\frac {1}{p^n}}+ \overline {\frac {1}{p^m}})=p^t.(\overline {\frac {1}{p^n}}+ \overline {\frac {1}{p^m}})= \overline {\frac {p^t}{p^n}}+ \overline {\frac {p^t}{p^m}}=f(\overline {\frac {1}{p^n}})+f(\overline {\frac {1}{p^m}})$

So $f$ is a homomorphism.

2. Given any $ \overline {\frac {p^t}{p^n}} \in \mathbb{Z} (p^\infty)$, we know that $f(\overline {\frac {1}{p^n}})=  \overline {\frac {p^t}{p^n}}$; therefore, $f(\mathbb{Z} (p^\infty))= \mathbb{Z} (p^\infty)$, which makes $f$ surjective.
3. $\ker f=\{ \overline {\frac {1}{p^n}}\ |\ f(\overline {\frac {1}{p^n}})=\bar{0}\}$

$\ker f=\{ \overline {\frac {1}{p^n}}\ |\ \overline {\frac {p^t}{p^n}}=\bar{0}=\overline{\frac{p^n}{p^n}}\}$

I couldn’t complete this part. Any help would be appreciated.

And are the answers for (1) and (2) correct? Thanks

Comment: You should say something more for $2$. What you want is for $f(\mathbb Z (p^\infty))$ to be the whole group $\mathbb  Z (p^\infty)$, hence you should see that each subgroup $\langle \overline{1/p^s}\rangle$ lies there. In particular, this is implied by having $\overline{1/p^s}$ in the image for each $s > 0$. Can you find some element of $x_s \in \mathbb Z(p^\infty)$ for which $f(x_s) = \overline{1/p_s}$?

Comment: Also, your computation of $3$ seems like you believe the only elements of $\mathbb Z(p^\infty)$ are of the form $\overline{1/p^n}$. Those elements *generate* the group, but they are not all possible ones.

Comment: You can find a more general answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3724989)

Comment: @FabioLucchini Thank you!